# Getters and Setters with pointers

Tags: c++

Okay so I'm a fairly new with C++ and I'm doing an assignment right now that requires many different classes. Now I'm experienced with Java and i may still have that programming mentality in my brain but my question is:

When you have two different classes, `A` and `B`, if `B` wants to access variables within `A`, I want to create a getter for the variable in `A`, but if that variable is a container that is heavy like a `std::map`, my question is would should i be making a getter that returns the pointer to the variable in A to access it in `B`?

Comment: Perhaps `A` can have a public member function that returns an iterator into the map.

Comment: In C++, getters and setters are often not used. In this case, the `map` could be public. If you insist on a getter, you can return a reference to keep it simple without needing pointers.

Comment: Also, consider making the reference `const` if you don't need to modify the variable.

Comment: @crashmstr _the map could be public_ I don't consider this a good idea! I'd still provide at least a getter for a private member, and return a reference to it.

Comment: Have you considered changing the design so that B doesn't want to access variables within A? This may not be possible, or at least not without major re-architecting, but good OO style tries to minimize getters.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if you want to get really "oop", you should abstract out the fact that it *is* a map...

Comment: @drocktapiff What makes you think `std::map` is _'heavy'_ BTW? For [tag:c++11] we have move semantics ...

Comment: You always need getter and setter for private members especially if your object is used in a multi-threading process. In fact in that case you need a mutex to protect the get and set operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For containers like a map, there is no objection if a getter returns a handle to access the object in place. It could be a pointer, but a reference might be more C++-ish.

For objects that are compositions - objects that "own" other objects - getters should normally not provide direct access. In Java you should not return the reference, and in C++ you should not return a pointer or reference. This, however, is more a style issue, following the advice of the OO pundits.

Comment: Thank you first of all! So design wise, should I maybe make B a friend of A, and make the map private therefore B can access the map directly?

Comment: Is a container not an object that contains other objects? I know what you're getting at, but it could do with rewording.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Yeah - one should use the correct terms ;-)

Comment: @drocktapiff It depends - how tightly you think A and B should be coupled. Friend is said to help with encapsulation, but also to undermine it, so it's very subtle and cannot be discussed in general terms. Design a useful interface for the combination so that clients aren't affected, and think about optimisations later.

Comment: @laune thank you very much this makes more sense, I guess it really depends on how the program has to be designed to chose which way to access the contents, I'll have to reread the assignment and go over how to design this program to have to proper structure. But thank you very much once again!